# How to get middle point of Matlab movegui() center - west?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I would like set my Matlab figure at the middle point of `center` and `west`. 
I can get center and west by the following but I cannot get their middle point; for instance the terms `westcenter` and `centerwest` do not work

```
movegui(hFig1,'center'); 
movegui(hFig2,'west'); 

% pseudo
movegui(hFig3,'westcenter/centerwest');
```

Matlab: 2016a
OS: Debian 8.5
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: I removed the answer part from your question. Questions are meant to contain only the question. I judged that your addition didn't give any addition to the already accepted answer you used, so there was no point in having that in the question. If you have something substantial to add, you are free to do so in a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the position manually. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movegui.html

```
pos = get(hFig1, 'Position');
ss = get(0,'screensize');
movegui(hFig1, [(ss(3) - pos(3))/4, (ss(4)-pos(4))/2]);
```

Comment: Please, see the body. I find parameters which puts the window precisely in center-west position in my system of 13" screen. - - Which display do you use?

Answer (score -1):

My final revision of user4567292's answer. 
The answer is at north, little west location but the idea is right

```
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/39818931/54964
pos = get(hFig1, 'Position');
ss = get(0,'screensize');
movegui(hFig_1_half, [(ss(3) - pos(3))/(2^2+2^1), (ss(4)-pos(4))/2^2]);
```

Output: precisely at center-west position.